# How to rbind large matrices and keep format and attributes in R?

Tags: r, matrix, raster

I have matrices like this one `z` - its how it looks in RStudio env.:

```
z            Large Matrix (625562 elements)
     attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
     ..$ : NULL
     ..$ : chr [1:3] "x" "y" "tif"
```

Now having more like this I try to combine the into one. I thought this would easy work

```
z0 = rbind(z0, z)
```

and it looks ok in plot but the format is wrong, like:

```
z0            Large Matrix (19530191 elements)
   : num 414640
   : num 414922
...
```

This cause problems with further functions. I tried to set attributes like `dimnames(z0) <- list(NULL, c("x", "y", "tif"))` and in fact the list itself is like that one from `z` but it doesn't apply. Please how to do it?

data structures:

```
> head(z0)
     x        y        tif
[1,] 454647.5 364856.5 0  
[2,] 454657.5 364856.5 0  
[3,] 454658.5 364856.5 0  
[4,] 454635.5 364855.5 0  
[5,] 454656.5 364855.5 0  
[6,] 454657.5 364855.5 0  

> head(z)
            x        y tif
[1,] 456170.5 361799.5   0
[2,] 456171.5 361799.5   0
[3,] 456181.5 361799.5   0
[4,] 456182.5 361799.5   0
[5,] 456192.5 361799.5   0
[6,] 456193.5 361799.5   0
```

Comment: What does `z0` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found what's wrong: in the loop initiator if the object shouldn't be a list.

```
z0 = list()
for (i in 1:K) {
   z0 = rbind(z0, z[i])
}
```

but `z0 = NULL`
Simple as that!

Comment: Doing `rbind` (or `c`) in a loop is an anti-pattern. First off, it’s overly verbose and complex. And secondly because it’s *very* inefficient, due to many redundant copies being made. A more concise, expressive and much more efficient implementation is `z0 = do.call(rbind, z)` … although this code assumes that `z` is a `list`, which doesn’t seem to be the case in your code. It’s not quite clear what `z` actually is, because if it’s a matrix then your `rbind` code doesn’t make much sense. If `z` *is* a matrix, just write `z0 = z` directly.